# jQuery interacting with a dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, html-select

How would you get jQuery to push a value in a dropdownlist as the selected value?

EX.
Dropdownlist has the options

`red
blue
yellow
green`

I want the jQuery to make "blue" the selected value in the dropdownlist.  jQuery reads what it has to push as the selected value from a variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select').find('option[value="blue"]').attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: 'select' is my drop down list.   But what is 'selected'?

Comment: `selected` is the attribute of the option.. Which points out what the selected option is.. `select` is the element.. You can give it a more specific selector

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `red blue yellow green` are the values of the existing options on your combo, this should do the trick

```
$("#yourddlid").val("blue");
```

Where `yourddlid` is the id of your dropdownlist

Comment: $('#ddlSalesman').val("testHolder");      This is the exact code I am using to accomplish this task.  All it is doing it making the selected value of the drop down, blank.  testHolder is a variable with the value I am trying to set in it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function:

```
$('#id_of_your_drop_down').val('yellow');
```